Unable to receive OTP message contain digits content Android
I am sending this message in Android using SMS API, message is sent from the device but the receiver number does not able to receive it.
My sent message is:
Your otp code is 3455. Thankyou!!
CODE:
  // notifies user
            String[] ph_numbers = message.split(",");
            SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
            for (String item : ph_numbers) {
                ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(title);
                sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(item, null, parts, null, null);
            }

But when I change above message content to below message content means when I remove the otp  digits, message gets received on receiver end
Your otp code is. Thankyou!!
Note: my sender device is in RCS mode and the receiver is also in RCS mode.
